# How to get the selected index of dynamically added radio buttons

Tags: android

I had added radio buttons dynamically like below.

```
for (int i = 0; i< typeArrayList.size(); i++) {
                   radioButtons[i] = new RadioButton(MainActivity.this);
                   radioButtons[i].setId(i);
                   radioButtons[i].setText(typeArrayList.get(i).toString());
                   if(i==0) {
                       radioButtons[i].setChecked(true);
                   }
                   typeLayout.addView( radioButtons[i]);
                }
```

I have a button when clicked calls a method to which the selected item (text) of the dynamically added radio buttons should be passed . How can I get the selected radio button text for the dynamically added radio buttons?

Comment: did you check our solutions

Answer (score 2):

Its very important to set your radio button id when adding buttons to a radio group.

```
RadioButton rb = new RadioButton(context);
rb.setText(option);
rb.setId(rb.hashCode());
radioGroup.addView(rb);
radioGroup.setOnCheckedChangeListener(mCheckedListner);
```

Now in your click listener check for the unique id.

```
private RadioGroup.OnCheckedChangeListener mCheckedListner = new RadioGroup.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
    @Override
    public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup group, int checkedId) {
        JSONArray actionArray = new JSONArray();
        if(group.findViewById(checkedId)!=null) {
            RadioButton rb = ((RadioButton) group.findViewById(checkedId)).getText();
//Your Code here
                }
            }
        }
    };
```

Answer (score 0):

You have stored all `RadioButtons` that you create dynamically in a `radioButtons array`.
So if you want to know which radiobutton is selected you can loop all this array and check each `RadioButton`

```
for (int i = 0; i< radioButtons.size(); i++) {
    if(radioButtons[i].isChecked()){
         // selected radio button is here
         String text = radioButtons[i].getText();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First you have to get all childs of your view. Then check if this view is RadioButton. And at last check which button is checked.

```
int childcount = typeLayout.getChildCount();
for (int i=0; i < childcount; i++){
      View view = typeLayout.getChildAt(i);
      if (view instanceof RadioButton) {
           if(((RadioButton)view).isChecked()) {
                RadioButton yourCheckedRadioButton = (RadioButton) typeLayout.getChildAt(i); // this is your checked RadioButton
           }
      }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

@Komali Shirumavilla

Add those dynamic radio buttons to radio group
so add following lines in your code

```
RadioGroup rg = new RadioGroup(this); //create the RadioGroup
rg.setOrientation(RadioGroup.HORIZONTAL);//or RadioGroup.VERTICAL
for (int i = 0; i< typeArrayList.size(); i++) {
radioButtons[i] = new RadioButton(MainActivity.this);
radioButtons[i].setId(i);
radioButtons[i].setText(typeArrayList.get(i).toString());
if(i==0) {
    radioButtons[i].setChecked(true);
}
rg.addView(radioButtons[i]);  // add dynamic radio buttons to radio group
}
typeLayout.addView(rg); // add radio group to view
```

Now set `setOnCheckedChangeListener` on the `RadioGroup`

```
rg.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new RadioGroup.OnCheckedChangeListener() {

            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup group, int checkedId) {
                switch(checkedId) {
                    RadioButton btn = (RadioButton)findViewById(checkedId);
                    Log.d("Your selected radio button id",btn.getText());
                }
            }
        });
```

Answer (score -1):

This can be simply achieved using **tags**.

While adding the `RadioButton` set a tag that particular object. In your case, set the tag to be the text of the radio button,

```
radioButtons[i].setTag(typeArrayList.get(i).toString());
```

This way all your **radio buttons will have the text associated to them** as a tag.

Now whenever a particular radio button is selected, just get the tag which will give you the text associated with it.

```
String text = (String) selectedRadioButton.getTag();
```

Hope it helps.